# List content being ignored

Tags: css

I have a list of calendar events. The html looks like this:

```
   <li data-id="1">
        <a href="#calendar-item/1">
            <div class="calendar" style="">
                    <div class="calendar-header"></div>
                    <div class="calendar-month">Dec</div>
                    <div class="calendar-day">11</div>
            </div>               
            <p>Parents Association Non-Uniform Day</p>
            <span class="chevron"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I have given the list item padding, but it is ignoring the content of the div tag, see the image:

[image]

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u72Q3/1/) is the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works in firefox for me but you defenitely need to clear your float. The easiest way to do that is using `overflow: hidden` on the list item so it takes the space of the floating icon and wraps its padding around that instead of just the text next to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this my be slow your problem

CSS

give flot:left in below class

```
li p:nth-of-type(1) {float:left;}
```

And give flot:left in below class

```
li{float:left;}
```